# How to deploy my play web App onto my server

Tags: java, web-applications, deployment, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have created a Web Application with the latest version of the play framework and am ready to deploy it. Since this is the first time I will deploy a web application onto a server I am not 100% sure how to to that.

I need to run a lot of cronjobs on the databases, which is why I have ordered a Vserver which came with Debian 7.8 LAMP installed.

What I am asking now is what is the simplest way to deploy my App onto my server?

What I would try if I wouldn't ask this question now, is to install play on my debian server (well actually I probably would have to install the activator thing nowadays instead right?) than upload my app to the server, change the deployment port of the app to 80, put the application in production mode and than start the app on the server or use the stage task command.

Is this the right way to do it? I do not want to make mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no right way to do it.

You have 4 choices (more if you include Maven distributions, etc.) but for the case 'I want to run my app on my server' there you go:

1. use `start` but it needs human intervention (interaction) so you might not want to do this in an actual production settings.
2. use `stage` to prepare your app for deployment. `stage` prepares some scripts which you can then call from /etc/init

The above methods NEED Play to be present on the server machine. So if you do not want to have Play! on your server... here you go:

3. use `dist` to create a zip file with everything in it... then just unzip the file somewhere in the server and run the scripts in the `bin` directory
4. Create a native package that will install your app as a (in your case) a Debian package.

Check this out (official docs):
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Production